# Fix bootstrap datepicker calendar position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, datetimepicker

On my site for some reason date picker calendar located lower that should be and therefore it obstructs the input. How can I fix its position?

[image]

http://test.rocknraw.ru/orders

Comment: No body can fix this issue without code. Please provide code buddy!!!

Comment: I think I found the property that is causing your issue, please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overwriting the `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget` CSS class and adding a `margin-bottom` property.

**EDIT**: I am looking at the control in your page and the `.datepicker` class has a `margin-top: 35px`; remove that property and it will be in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

First - I dont know your codes.

Second - If your issue cant be fixed by your self, try to create a div or popover and give an input date time picker inside that div to replacing position.

Final - This is my codes to use my second argument.

Codes :

```
$('#date_time').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'id',
            toolbarPlacement: 'bottom',
            showTodayButton: true,
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            allowInputToggle: true,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
            icons: {
            time: 'glyphicon glyphicon-time',
            date: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar',
            up: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
            down: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
            previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left',
            next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right',
            today: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home',
            clear: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash',
            close: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'
            },
            tooltips: {
            today: 'Hari ini',
            clear: 'Hapus masukan',
            close: 'Tutup',
            selectMonth: 'Pilih bulan',
            prevMonth: 'Bulan sebelumnya',
            nextMonth: 'Bulan berikutnya',
            selectYear: 'Pilih tahun',
            prevYear: 'Tahun sebelumnya',
            nextYear: 'Tahun berikutnya',
            selectDecade: 'Pilih dasawarsa',
            prevDecade: 'Dasawarsa sebelumnya',
            nextDecade: 'Dasawarsa berikutnya',
            prevCentury: 'Abad sebelumnya',
            nextCentury: 'Abad berikutnya',
            pickHour: 'Pilih jam',
            incrementHour: 'Jam selanjutnya',
            decrementHour: 'Jam sebelumnya',
            pickMinute: 'Pilih menit',
            incrementMinute: 'Menit selanjutnya',
            decrementMinute: 'Menit sebelumnya',
            pickSecond: 'Pilih detik',
            incrementSecond: 'Detik selanjutnya',
            decrementSecond: 'Detik sebelumnya',
            togglePeriod: 'Ubah am/pm',
            selectTime: 'Pilih waktu'
            }
        });
        $('#calendar-status').click(function(event) {
        $('.elmahbub-popover-bottom').css('width', 'auto').slideToggle().after().parent().css('position', 'relative');
    });
```

And html :

```
<button class="btn-xs pull-right margin-secondary btn-border bg-white icon-attachment" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="calendar-status" title="Tanggal"><b class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar grey fontsize-xsmall"></b></button>
<div class="input-group date elmahbub-date-time-picker elmahbub-popover-bottom">
                <div align="center">
                <span class="fontsize-xsmall black roboto margin-bottom10">Tanggal dan waktu</span>
                <input id="date_time" type="text" name="tanggal_status" placeholder="Masukkan tanggal dan waktu" class="form-control fontsize-xsmall" style="height:28px">
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `orientation` option.
Take a look to its [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#orientation)